# Can I program an ATtiny87 with Arduino

Tags: attiny

I have a project, and I want to use an ATtiny167(ATtiny87), I know that an Arduino can progam ATtiny84 (84/44/24), ATtiny85 (85/45/25), and ATtiny2313 (4313). **but I don't know if it can program an ATtiny87?**

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a json for ATtiny 167 at https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoOnOtherAtmelChips

So add that json to your preferenses.

Comment: Having same issue. Installed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damellis/attiny/ide-1.6.x-boards-manager/package_damellis_attiny_index.json already. Trying to program the Roshamglo with virtual USB 1.1 via Micronucleus but even when the device is in and in Bootloader mode, I can not see it with `lsusb` or in `micronucleus`. Any suggestions?